# R IDs error checking (different names, same ID)

Tags: r

I have data with a list of people's names and their ID numbers. Not all people with the same name will have the same ID number but everyone with different names should have a different ID number. Like this:

```
Name  david david john john john john megan bill barbara chris chris

ID     1      1    2    2    2    3   4    5    6   7   8
```

I need to make sure that these IDs are correct. So, I want to write a code that says "subset only if ID numbers are the same but their names are different"(so I will be only subsetting ID errors). I don't even know where to start with this because I tried

```
df1<-df(subset(duplicated(df$Name) & duplicated(df$ID)))
Error in subset.default(duplicated(df$officer) & duplicated(df$ID)) : 
  argument "subset" is missing, with no default
```

but it didn't work and I know it doesn't tell R to match and compare names and ID numbers.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated with the information in the comments below

Here are some test data:

```
> DF <- data.frame(name = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"), id=c(1,1,2,3,4,4))
> DF
  name id
1    A  1
2    A  1
3    A  2
4    B  3
5    B  4
6    C  4
```

So ... if I understand your problem correctly you want to get the information that there are problems with id 4 since two different names (B and C) appear for that id.

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(id) %>% distinct(name) %>% tally()
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     id     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     1
2     2     1
3     3     1
4     4     2
```

Here we get a summary and see that there are two different names (`n`) for `id` 4. You can combine that with `filter` to only see the ids with more than one name

```
> DF %>% group_by(id) %>% distinct(name) %>% tally() %>% filter(n > 1)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
     id     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     4     2
```

Did that help?

Comment: You are right! I was messing up the subset command but the command I wrote down doesn't exactly do what I wanted it to do anyway. When I run that command, it gives me the whole data set - not just the ones with different names and same ID numbers. :(

Comment: Sorry, I was struggling with formatting the data to match the format for this website!!!! The above example I gave is fine - if I subset that, the results should be 0 observations. If John's ID is a 3 and Chris's ID is also a 3, then it becomes a problem. And I need to know how many there are of these (people with different names but they have the same ID number) in my dataset (I found a couple so far by just looking at the data)